# Bash read command - how to accept control characters

Tags: bash

I am using the following to read a bunch of parameters from the user.

```
read -p "Name`echo $'\n> '`" NAME
```

All my parameters have default values. I want to provide an option to the user to skip providing values at any point. i.e. user might provide values for first 3 parameters and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to skip entering values for the rest of them.

How can I trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>?

Comment: You can only trap signals, as far as I know. Notice that Ctrl + S already has [significance for some terminal emulators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137842/what-is-the-point-of-ctrl-s), but I'm not sure if you can make this "trappable".

Comment: The user can enter Ctrl+S by typing Ctrl+V and the Ctrl+S.

Comment: Ctrl + [any character] works for me. Want to know how to trap it

Comment: Would it be easier to recognize 'empty input' as meaning 'no value'?

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+S is the terminal scroll lock character, and is not immediately available. You have two options:

- Work with the system, use the system standard key combos, and make life easier for yourself and everyone else.
- Fight the system, insist on using this key combo, do anything it takes to make it happen, and then live with the consequences.

If you want to work with the system, consider using a blank line and/or Ctrl+D, which is already extensively used to end input. This is easy and robust:

```
if read -p "Name (or blank for done)"$'\n> ' name && [[ $name ]]
then
  echo "User entered $name"
else
  echo "User is done entering things"
fi
```

Alternatively, here's a start for fighting the system:

```
#!/bin/bash
settings=$(stty -g)
echo "Enter name or ctrl+s to stop:"
stty stop undef    # or 'stty raw' to read other control chars

str=""
while IFS= read -r -n 1 c && [[ $c ]]
do
  [[ $c = $'\x13' ]] && echo "Ctrl+S pressed" && break
  str+="$c"
done
echo "Input was $str"
stty "$settings"
```

This will correctly end when the user hits Ctrl+S on a standard configuration, but since it doesn't work with the system, it needs additional work to support proper line editing and less common configurations.

Comment: Nothing like the simplicity and logic of "Door #1 -- and you'll be fine." or "Door #2 -- and have bamboo forced under your fingernails." -- your choice...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by trapping.  The user can input Ctrl+S by typing Ctrl+V and then Ctrl+S, and your script can then do the check:

```
if [[ $NAME == '^S' ]]; then
  ...
  # skip asking for more values and continue with default values
fi
```

Comment: What does Ctrl+V do here?

Comment: @pc70: The control-V indicates that the next character should be processed 'verbatim' — as a character and not do anything special.  It suppresses special meanings for control-D, control-Z, control-C, control-S, control-Q, ...